# checkout scm in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following advanced scripted pipeline in a Jenkinsfile:

```
stage('Generate') {
    node {
        checkout scm
    }

    parallel windows: {
        node('windows') {
            sh 'cmake . -Bbuild.windows -A x64'
        }
    },
    macos: {
        node('apple') {
            sh '/usr/local/bin/cmake . -DPLATFORM="macos" -Bbuild.macos -GXcode'
        }
    },
    ios: {
        node('apple') {
            sh '/usr/local/bin/cmake . -DPLATFORM="ios" -Bbuild.ios -GXcode'
        }
    }
}
```

Note the top `node` that precedes the parallel windows/macos/ios nodes. Does this mean that `checkout scm` will be invoked on every subsequent building node (windows/apple), before proceeding to the parallel steps? In other words, does the script above guarantee that the repository will be checked out on every node that will be involved at any stage of this build?

Many thanks.

Comment: The build doesn't fail consistently, it fails intermittently.

Comment: Sure, it works on that agent that has the source checked out. If that agent has the label 'apple' and is re-used in this or a later build (because you do not clean up the workspace), then the code is still lying on disk.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The first `node` step will allocate any build agent and check out the source code.
Later, additional nodes will be allocated, where I can promise you that `cmake` will fail, as it works with an empty directory.

You can use [`stash` and `unstash`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build) to copy over the files that are needed for the build (and subsequent stages):

```
stage('Generate') {
    node {
        checkout scm
        stash 'source'
    }

    parallel windows: {
        node('windows') {
            unstash 'source'
            sh 'cmake . -Bbuild.windows -A x64'
        }
    },
    macos: {
        node('apple') {
            unstash 'source'
            sh '/usr/local/bin/cmake . -DPLATFORM="macos" -Bbuild.macos -GXcode'
        }
    },
    ios: {
        node('apple') {
            unstash 'source'
            sh '/usr/local/bin/cmake . -DPLATFORM="ios" -Bbuild.ios -GXcode'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `stash` transfer the files from the agent to the master?

Comment: No, it transfers them from the node where `stash` is called to the master. `unstash` transfers it back from the master to the node where it is called.